# Remove files after an accidential git add of files.

Tags: git

I accidentally added in swap files from my editor when doing a git add. How do I selectively just remove those 2 files? And say if it was 100 accidentally added files, how would one handle that?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `git rm --cached <FileToRemove>`, the file is only removed from the index but not from the working tree / directory.

Comment: And to follow up the "say if it was 100 accidentally added files" part, you could either use wildcards, or just undo the commit (*only if you have not published it!*) with `git reset HEAD~1`.

Answer (score 1):

I use `git rm <FilesToRemove>` - [Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html).

As a slight aside, I find [This Diagram](http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html) really helpful as a quick reference.

Edit: As Dirk points out, if you run this without the `--cached` flag, it will remove your file from the working directory as well as the index, always be careful with uncommited changes.

Comment: You have to mention that the file will be deleted from disk / working directory with that command!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `git add -i` to enter interactive mode. You can `revert` those files you added mistakenly from there.